# How to block user using older version of my App?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm developing an application using flex/AIR and right now it changes all the time due to its beta condition.

What could be the best way to block all older versions activity and force the user to update the application?

Thanks.

Edit: This must be achieved without any server side language help (ie: php, java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best shot is to add an autoupdater to your app, and run it when starting your application. Check the [Adobe AIR autoupdate framework](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html#WS9CD40F06-4DD7-4230-B56A-88AA27541A1E). You can implement your logic (blocking the application, asking to update, closing it) after you have compared the versions if doesn't match.

This article might also be helpful: [Adding autoupdate features to your air application in 3  easy steps](http://gregsramblings.com/2008/08/16/adding-auto-update-features-to-your-air-application-in-3-easy-steps/)  (Actually it is a 2 Steps now).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an entry method that checks the applications local version against the remote version number via a service you expose. If the local version does not match your newest version, don't allow the application to proceed.  Instead, offer the download link, or automate the downloading/installation process based on your needs.

Comment: Like sending the app version through a httpservice and then returning an ok to continue or a function call order for update.. yes. But I really need it to be without any server side connection.